# x/.NSolve[f==g,x] does not work when f or g is the output of NDSolve!

Tags: equation-solving

I have been trying to put Points at the intersection of two curves, one of which is the ouput of a differential equation solved with NDSolve. The output being an Interpolation, NSolve cannot find the intersection coordinates.

Comment: `NSolve[]` wouldn't be up to the task here, as it's mostly intended for *algebraic* equations. Why not mention the particular "curves" whose intersections you seek? Maybe the differential equation too, while you're at it...

Comment: The [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NSolve.html) do mention that "NSolve deals primarily with linear and polynomial equations." Maybe you should try with `FindRoot`, but that locates one root at a time as it's a fully numerical function.

Comment: Bonjour & bienvenue sur Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
 2)[`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking 
the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system 
is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to 
accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, 
[`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 5):

I would use `FindRoot` in this case. For example:

```
solution1=NDSolve[{y'[x]==2y[x],y[0]==1},y[x],{x,-1,1}][[1,1,2]];
solution2=NDSolve[{y'[x]==-3y[x],y[0]==3},y[x],{x,-1,1}][[1,1,2]];
Plot[{solution1,solution2,solution1-solution2},{x,-1,1}]
FindRoot[solution1-solution2,{x,0}]
```

With the results:

[image]

Comment: I could not get FindRoot to work when one functionF"f" is the result of NDSolve and the other function "g"is

Comment: I could not get FindRoot to work when "f" is the output of NDSolve and "g" is a simple function like y=2x!

Comment: @Jean, as you've been told previously, edit your question to include the *Mathematica* code you already have, including the `NDSolve[]` bits.