# NSolve with ParametricFunction

Tags: equation-solving, parametric-functions

I have solved a SDE with ParametricNDSolve:

```
s = ParametricNDSolve[
      {p1, m1, p0, m0}, {P, m}, {r, 0, 1}, {m, k, e, Cnew}
    ]
```

And now I want to treat the parameters `m, k, e, Cnew` as variables because I want to evaluate conditions like `P[m, k, e, Cnew][1] == 0`.

How can I plot the condition (for example) `P[m, k, 1, 1][1] == 0`?

I have tried doing:

```
f[r_, m_, k_, e_, Cnew_] := Evaluate[P[m_, k_, e_, Cnew_][r] /. s]
```

But, using `NSolve` (with `k = 1`, for example):

```
NSolve[f[1, m, 1, 1, 1] == 0, m]
```

I get: `{}`

I have also done the plot for `k=1`:

```
Plot[f[1, m, 1, 1, 0] , {m, 0, 11}]
```

getting good results for `k=1`.

**Edit:**

Runnable code with a simpler example:

```
p1 = P'[r] == -m*r + k*r^2;
p0 = P[0] == 1;
s = ParametricNDSolve[{p1, p0}, {P}, {r, 0, 1}, {m, k}];
f[r_, m_, k_] := Evaluate[P[m, k][r] /. s]

NSolve[f[r, 1, 1] == 0, r]  (*That's ok*)

NSolve[f[1, m, 1] == 0, m]  (*But this...*)

NSolve[f[1, m, k] == 0, m]  (*And this... that is what I really want*)

Plot[f[1, m, 1], {m, 0, 5}] (*But this works!*)
```

I'm searching the expression m = m(k) from `f[1, m, k] == 0`

Comment: Please provide runable code to make answering easier!.

Comment: Ok, I have written it in the edit.

Comment: Have you tried `FindRoot`? `NSolve` is built for systems expressible as a polynomial system, many transcendental equations over bounded domains, and perhaps a few special cases.  The first works because `InverseFunction` works on `InterpolatingFunction`, but it will return only one solution. `NSolve` does not seem to handle `ParametricFunction`, though, if so, it should give an error meessage. To solve the last equation, use `DSolve` instead of `ParametricNDSolve` and `Solve` instead of `NSolve`.

Comment: Or if there's no symbolic solution that `DSolve` can obtain, then you'll probably have to construct a numerical solution for $m=m(k)$. For example, solve at several points and interpolate. Or `mFN[k_] := Module[{m}, m /. FindRoot[f[1, m, k] == 0, {m, 1}]]`.  You might want to figure out a better starting point for `FindRoot` than the `1` in `{m, 1}`.

Comment: Yes, what I finally did was use a double for loop (for three parameters) with FindRoot. I was searching for "analytic" results to plot a `ContourPlot` with `r=1` but I will be content with plotting lists. Thank you so much!

Comment: I think that it is the only solution to this problem, so if you make an answer you will get my green tick.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/236406/4999